# How to extract string from large file only if specific string appears previous using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I am trying to extract information from a large file and cannot figure out how to extract strings from file lines only when a previous line in the same record within the file has been matched by regex.  An example of one record in the file is as follows:

```
*NEW RECORD
RECTYPE = D
MH = Informed Consent
AQ = ES HI LJ PX SN ST
ENTRY = Consent, Informed
MN = N03.706.437.650.312
MN = N03.706.535.489
FX = Disclosure
FX = Mental Competency
FX = Therapeutic Misconception
FX = Treatment Refusal
ST = T058
ST = T078
AN = competency to consent: coordinate IM with MENTAL COMPETENCY (IM)
PI = Jurisprudence (1966-1970)
PI = Physician-Patient Relations (1966-1970)
MS = Voluntary authorization, by a patient or research subject, etc,...
```

This file contains over 20,000 records like this example.  I want to identify a small percent of those records using the "MH" field.  In this example, I want to find "Informed Consent", and then use regex to extract the information in the FX, AN, and MS fields only within that record.  So far, I have opened the file, accessed the hash that the MH terms are stored in, and been able to extract those terms from the records in the file.  I also have a functioning regex that identifies the content in the "FX" field.

```
File.open('mesh_descriptor.bin').each do |file_line|
file_line = file_line.chomp

# read each key of candidate_descriptor_keys
candidate_descriptor_keys.each do |cand_term|

  if file_line =~ /^MH\s=\s(#{cand_term})$/
  mesh_header = $1
  puts "MH from Mesh Descriptor file is: #{mesh_header}"


    if file_line =~ /^FX\s=\s(.*)$/
    see_also = $1
    puts " See_Also from Descriptor file is: #{see_also}"
  end   
 end
end
end
```

The hash contains the following MH (keys):

```
candidate_descriptor_keys = ["Body Weight", "Obesity", "Thinness", "Fetal Weight", "Overweight"]
```

I had success extracting "FX" when I put the statement outside of the "if" statement to extract "MH", but all of the "FX" from the whole file were retrieved - not what I need.  I thought putting the "if" statement for "FX" within the previous "if" statement would restrict the results to only those found when the first statement is true, but I am getting no results (also no errors) with this strategy.  What I would like as a result is:

```
> Informed Consent
> Disclosure
> Mental Competency
> Therapeutic Misconception
> Treatment Refusal
```

as well as the strings within the "AN" and "MS" fields for only those records matching "MH".  Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Right before the `Code` section of my answer I have written several lines that begin, "I have assumed...".  I suggest you add something like that to your question, perhaps right after your paragraph that ends " The script so far is as follows:" (and move that sentence to follow the added text).  Once you've done that I'll remove that part of my answer.  If you want to use what I've written, I have no objection.

Comment: Readers: I had a lengthy conversation with the asker (in comments). If you do not understand the question, please read the beginning of my answer before the "Code" section.  Also note the asker's comment on my answer.  Tomorrow the asker will clean up the question and delete his/her comments, which are no longer relevant.  (I've already deleted mine.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be what you are looking for, but if not, let me know and I will change it.  Look especially at the very end to see if that is the sort of output (for input having two records, both with a "MH" field) you want.  I will also add a "explanation" section at the end once I have understood your question correctly.

I have assumed that each record begins

```
*NEW_RECORD
```

and you wish to identify all lines beginning `"MH"` whose field is one of the elements of:

```
candidate_descriptor_keys =
  ["Body Weight", "Obesity", "Thinness", "Informed Consent"]
```

and for each match, you would like to print the contents of the lines for the same record that begin with `"FX"`, `"AN"` and `"MS"`.

**Code**

```
NEW_RECORD_MARKER = "*NEW RECORD"

def getem(fname, candidate_descriptor_keys)
  line = 0
  found_mh = false
  File.open(fname).each do |file_line|
    file_line = file_line.strip
    case
    when file_line == NEW_RECORD_MARKER
      puts # space between records
      found_mh = false
    when found_mh == false
      candidate_descriptor_keys.each do |cand_term|
        if file_line =~ /^MH\s=\s(#{cand_term})$/
          found_mh = true
          puts "MH from line #{line} of file is: #{cand_term}"
          break
        end  
      end  
    when found_mh
      ["FX", "AN", "MS"].each do |des| 
        if file_line =~ /^#{des}\s=\s(.*)$/
          see_also = $1
          puts " Line #{line} of file is: #{des}: #{see_also}"
        end
      end
    end
    line += 1
  end
end
```

**Example**

Let's begin be creating a file, starging with a "here document that contains two records":

```
records =<<_
*NEW RECORD
RECTYPE = D
MH = Informed Consent
AQ = ES HI LJ PX SN ST
ENTRY = Consent, Informed
MN = N03.706.437.650.312
MN = N03.706.535.489
FX = Disclosure
FX = Mental Competency
FX = Therapeutic Misconception
FX = Treatment Refusal
ST = T058
ST = T078
AN = competency to consent
PI = Jurisprudence (1966-1970)
PI = Physician-Patient Relations (1966-1970)
MS = Voluntary authorization
*NEW RECORD
MH = Obesity
AQ = ES HI LJ PX SN ST
ENTRY = Obesity
MN = N03.706.437.650.312
MN = N03.706.535.489
FX = 1st FX
FX = 2nd FX
AN = Only AN
PI = Jurisprudence (1966-1970)
PI = Physician-Patient Relations (1966-1970)
MS = Only MS
_
```

If you `puts records` you will see it is just a string.  (You'll see that I shortened two of them.)  Now write it to a file:

```
File.write('mesh_descriptor', records)
```

If you wish to confirm the file contents, you could do this:

```
puts File.read('mesh_descriptor')
```

We also need to define define the array `candidate_descriptor_keys`:

```
candidate_descriptor_keys =
  ["Body Weight", "Obesity", "Thinness", "Informed Consent"]
```

We can now execute the method `getem`:

```
getem('mesh_descriptor', candidate_descriptor_keys)

MH from line 2 of file is: Informed Consent
 Line 7 of file is: FX: Disclosure
 Line 8 of file is: FX: Mental Competency
 Line 9 of file is: FX: Therapeutic Misconception
 Line 10 of file is: FX: Treatment Refusal
 Line 13 of file is: AN: competency to consent
 Line 16 of file is: MS: Voluntary authorization

MH from line 18 of file is: Obesity
 Line 23 of file is: FX: 1st FX
 Line 24 of file is: FX: 2nd FX
 Line 25 of file is: AN: Only AN
 Line 28 of file is: MS: Only MS
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer!  Your assumptions are correct, and the output is what I am looking for.  I will get back to writing the script tomorrow and give you feedback - Thank you!

Comment: I think the `case` statement is OK.  When `case` is not followed by anything, it executes the first `when` that evaluates `true`, which is what we want, as we checking `file_line == NEW_RECORD_MARKER`, then `found_mh == false`.  Leave `def getem(fname, candidate_descriptor_keys)` as is; call it with: getem("mesh_descriptor.bin", candidate_descriptor_keys)`. If you run it from the terminal, make sure the current directory contains "mesh_descriptor.bin" before invoking Ruby (so it can find it). If you still have the problem, please give me the exact error message and the line where it occurs.